# CSS transition seems to work everywhere... except one computer

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://jordankline.design/designs.html

I have a CSS fade in animation on each of those tiles that reveals the name of each project when you hover. It works perfectly on every browser I've tried... except Chrome on my friend's computer, where the animation only occurs when you click (instead of hover). We have the same operating system (Windows) and the same version of Chrome (51.0.2704.106), so I'm not sure what's happening. My only guess is that it might have something to do with her monitor having touch capabilities?

Here's the CSS for the relevant class:

```
.boxInner .titleBox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 38%;

    background: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: MinionPro;
    font-size: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
} 

body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your `:hover`  selector starts with `body.no-touch`, so I would assume that you use JavaScript to add / remove that class depending on whether or not touch capabilities are detected...

Comment: Hello, I know this is completely unrelated to your question, but I can't help myself. First off, the submit on your contact form has no hover state :( Secondly, isn't there too much hovering for the header? I feel that the `home` button is enough. Just my opinion though, otherwise I love the design of the site! :)

Comment: The touch class might be enabled by a drawing pad, like a Wacom. I have had this experience with a Cintiq screen.

Comment: Michael - I agree with both points! It's my friend's website, and she really wanted her logo/name clickable even though the Home button already does it. As for the Submit button, I kept putting it off and eventually forgot... : ) I must admit the (excellent) design is all hers, too.. she gave me a PDF of how she wanted everything and I just tried to make it into a website. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I'll pursue the touchscreen route some more and see if I can fix it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Add this (since you have no focus or hover selector):

```
a:hover .titleBox, a:focus .titleBox {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The `:focus` ensures it works for keyboard users as well.